# Why don't I get HIGH on output pins of MCP23S17?

Tags: c, stm32, microchip

I use a STM32 connected with SPI to a MCP23S17 16 bit I/O port expander.

I want to make all 16 I/0 pins as output and just making them all LOW or HIGH.

I used an oscilloscope to check is SPI transmit the signals right, and it does.
The only thing is that on the I/O pins I get around 0.4V. Not 5V.

Sometimes I get a value of 1.4V but it goes away, weird thing...

Can somebody check my code and tell me where is my mistake? I am pretty sure I did the code wrong somewhere.

MCP23S17.h:

```
#ifndef INC_MCP23S17_H_
#define INC_MCP23S17_H_

#include "stm32f1xx_hal_conf.h"

extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;

void MCP23S17_SPI_Write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data);
uint8_t MCP23S17_SPI_Read(uint8_t data);

#define CS_HIGH() HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
#define CS_LOW() HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);




#define MCP23S17_AAA        ((uint8_t)0x0E)
#define MCP23S17_ADDRESS    ((uint8_t)0x40)

#define MCP23S17_W          ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define MCP23S17_R          ((uint8_t)0x01)

#define MCP23S17_IODIRA     ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define MCP23S17_IPOLA      ((uint8_t)0x02)
#define MCP23S17_GPINTENA   ((uint8_t)0x04)
#define MCP23S17_DEFVALA    ((uint8_t)0x06)
#define MCP23S17_INTCONA    ((uint8_t)0x08)
#define MCP23S17_IOCONA     ((uint8_t)0x0A)
#define MCP23S17_GPPUA      ((uint8_t)0x0C)
#define MCP23S17_INTFA      ((uint8_t)0x0E)
#define MCP23S17_INTCAPA    ((uint8_t)0x10)
#define MCP23S17_GPIOA      ((uint8_t)0x12)
#define MCP23S17_OLATA      ((uint8_t)0x14)


#define MCP23S17_IODIRB     ((uint8_t)0x01)
#define MCP23S17_IPOLB      ((uint8_t)0x03)
#define MCP23S17_GPINTENB   ((uint8_t)0x05)
#define MCP23S17_DEFVALB    ((uint8_t)0x07)
#define MCP23S17_INTCONB    ((uint8_t)0x09)
//#define MCP23S17_IOCONB   ((uint8_t)0x0B)
#define MCP23S17_GPPUB      ((uint8_t)0x0D)
#define MCP23S17_INTFB      ((uint8_t)0x0F)
#define MCP23S17_INTCAPB    ((uint8_t)0x11)
#define MCP23S17_GPIOB      ((uint8_t)0x13)
#define MCP23S17_OLATB      ((uint8_t)0x15)




//#define MCP23S17_INT_ERR  ((uint8_t)255)

//#define BANK              ((uint8_t)0x80) //bit 7  of IOCON
//#define MIRROR                ((uint8_t)0x40) //bit 6  of IOCON
//#define SEQOP                 ((uint8_t)0x20) //bit 5  of IOCON
//#define DISSLW                ((uint8_t)0x10) //bit 4  of IOCON
//#define HAEN              ((uint8_t)0x08) //bit 3  of IOCON
//#define ODR                   ((uint8_t)0x04) //bit 2  of IOCON
//#define INTPOL                ((uint8_t)0x02) //bit 1  of IOCON
//#define unused                ((uint8_t)0x00) //bit 0  of IOCON


//-----------------------

#define MCP23S17_MODERA_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_IODIRA, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_MODERA_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_IODIRA)

#define MCP23S17_IPOLA_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_IPOLA, ((uint8_t)x))


#define MCP23S17_ODRA_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_OLATA, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_ODRA_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_OLATA)

#define MCP23S17_IDRA_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_GPIOA)     // Reflect the value of the port A

#define MCP23S17_PUDA_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_GPPUA, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_PUDA_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_GPPUA)

#define MCP23S17_SETUP_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_IOCONA, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_SETUP_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_IOCONA))

#define MCP23S17_MODERB_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_IODIRB, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_MODERB_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_IODIRB)

#define MCP23S17_IPOLB_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_IPOLB, ((uint8_t)x))


#define MCP23S17_ODRB_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_OLATB, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_ODRB_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_OLATB)

#define MCP23S17_IDRB_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_GPIOB)     // Reflect the value of the port B

#define MCP23S17_PUDB_W(x) MCP23S17_SPI_Write(MCP23S17_GPPUB, ((uint8_t)x))
#define MCP23S17_PUDB_R() MCP23S17_SPI_Read(MCP23S17_GPPUB)

//-----------------------

void GPIO_Write_Pins(uint16_t);
void GPIO_Expander_Init();
void MCP23S17_SPI_Write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data);
#endif /* INC_MCP23S17_H_ */
```

MCP23S17.c

```
#include "main.h"
#include "MCP23S17.h"

void MCP23S17_SPI_Write(uint8_t reg_addr, uint8_t data)
{
    uint8_t pBuff[3];
    pBuff[0] = MCP23S17_ADDRESS|MCP23S17_AAA|MCP23S17_W;    //optocode that contain 0100 + 111 + 0 (read command)
    pBuff[1] = reg_addr;  // register address
    pBuff[2] = data;      // the value that is modified on the register, check datasheet

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

    HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT(&hspi2, pBuff, 3);  //transmit on the spi2 the optocode, register adress and the value for the register
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 85; i++)    //delay
        {}

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
}
void GPIO_Expander_Init()
{
    MCP23S17_SETUP_W(0x00);
    MCP23S17_MODERA_W(0x00);
    MCP23S17_MODERB_W(0x00);
    MCP23S17_PUDA_W(0x00);
    MCP23S17_PUDB_W(0x00);
    //MCP23S17_IPOLA_W(0x00);
    //MCP23S17_IPOLB_W(0x00);

}
void GPIO_Write_Pins(uint16_t dataspi)
{
    //16 to 8 and 8
    uint8_t data_half[2];

    data_half[0]=*((uint8_t*)&(dataspi)+1);     //split the first half of the data
    data_half[1]=*((uint8_t*)&(dataspi)+0);     //split the second half of the data

    MCP23S17_ODRA_W(data_half[0]);  //first half
    MCP23S17_ODRB_W(data_half[1]);  //second half

}
```

and in main.c

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);


  GPIO_Expander_Init();

  GPIO_Write_Pins(0xFFFF);
  while(1)
  {

  }
```

Comment: I am familiar with STM32F4 instead of F1. You may have have not posted all your code but my question is: where to you initialize your GPIOs?

Comment: How would they be initialized?

Comment: I use GPIO_Expander_Init(); to call for IOCON register with Setup_W, IODIRA with MODERA_W, etc

Comment: `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT()` is asynchronous (non-blocking), but then you use a busy-loop to "guess" when to deassert the /CS.  You should either wait on `SPI_CheckFlag_BSY()` or use the blocking  `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` - I think, the documentation for the HAL is abysmal, and I seldom use it.

Comment: ok ok, this is a good idea, I will try it.

Comment: So _"I used an oscilloscope to check is SPI transmit the signals right, and it does."_ is not in fact the case then?  You really need a logic analyser rather then a scope - unless you have four channels.

Comment: I have multiple channels, like digital wires, D0, D1,D2,D3, and more. Like I see the signals and checked if are correct, 01001110000101000000000 for example.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong with the CS that doesnt let the data to get correctly inside MCP23S17.

Comment: Some notes: The `CS_HIGH()`/`CS_LOW()` macros are not used, instead you set the CS pin like this: `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, ...);`. Is this the correct pin and is it configured as digital output (pullup?), do you see it go LOW/HIGH? - Do you see the IC reacting on the logic analyzer/scope when you write to a register? - Also, I'd use the blocking write/read variant `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` instead of `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT()` for testing.

Comment: Sounds like your scope is in fact a logic analyser (too).  If you have a multi-channel logic trace, that shows what is happening, it would be a good idea to include a screenshot with  the question. _" 01001110000101000000000 for example"_ tells me _nothing_!  Clearly the /CS should be low for the duration of the active SCK clock.

Comment: @rel Good spot.  Also to use asynchronous non-blocking  `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT()` to only then "busy-wait" is pointless.  Its purpose is to allow other work to be done while waiting for the completion handler to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So coming back with the solution, the code was good, 2 first gpio expanders that I tried were purely burned. For a much shorter working code just comment here asking for it. Thank everyone for advices cause I took them in consideration in the final form of code.

Comment: Hi, I'm using MCP23S08 with STM32F4 as well and I would much appreciate it if you could share the code with me for some dev insights on how to interact with this chip.

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing is that on the I/O pins I get around 0.4V

This is likely because GPIOs are not initialized.

You also have a different problem to deal with.

```
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 85; i++)    //delay
{}
```

This loop is very likely to be optimize away by the compiler. This is because, it doesn't do anything.

There are more sophisticated ways of generating delays in a microcontroller. The best possible solution would be to use a timer module.

Comment: The part about the delay loop is a comment, not an answer - It is valid, but should be posted as a comment. unless it causes the failure of the I/O  problem, which you don't seem to think so.

Comment: @clifford: I agree with your point entirely. I am still working on the GPIO issue now.

Comment: Actually I have changed my mind, the delay is relevant.  The `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT()` is asynchronous, so it is likely that the /CS is de-asserted before the data is transmitted.  The code should wait until the transmit is complete or use `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()`

Comment: The proper way is always to wait for the relevant SPI flag, not to use busy-delays. And most STM32 got DMA too, consider using it.

Comment: @Clifford, my CS signal is actually like this ____|data__|data__ Like is going up before the data and it goes down.

Comment: @Akatori: Like @Clifford already pointed out above, that might be the main issue here! Good, that you've checked the actual signal. - Since you're using the interrupt based SPI transmit function (`HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT()`), the CS pin will already be in HIGH state before the operation finished. Quick fix: Replace `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT` with `HAL_SPI_Transmit`. The CS pin must be LOW during the entire duration of the communication to that slave IC.

Comment: @rel : But the void GPIO_Expander_Init(){.......} is corect for making all the pins output?

Comment: @Akatori: Before caring about the application, I'd try to make sure that the basic SPI communication is working correctly (e.g. by writing to a register and reading the value back). To do that, also check the SPI polarity and clock speed, peripheral configuration and really make sure to connect the right pins. - Once that part is working, it's getting easier and you can start to implement the driver step by step, by reading the datasheet very carefully and testing out every function you'll need. - You could also find many examples for that chip (e.g. for Arduino), when you search the web.

Comment: How I can check the SPI polarity?

Comment: Either by studying the MCP23S17 datasheet and SPI basics carefully and/or "trial and error" (there are only 4 options (CPOL=0/1 and CPHA=0/1)). If you're using STM32CubeMX, you can configure the SPI clock polarity/phase in the peripheral settings, and also change SPI clock speed in the clock tree (via divider, it must be below 10 MHz in your case -> start slow). - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface#Clock_polarity_and_phase / https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf (BTW: also check Note 1 on page 8, FIGURE 1-5:SPI INPUT TIMING on SPI modes)